# Masonry - IE11 not loading it with .load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

**EDIT to explain better**

Some Masonry code it's not loaded in IE11.

I load the HTML code inside a page, and this one it's loaded with `.load()` in a main page.

If the following code is placed inside the javascript file it fails. But, if I put this code inside the `.load(function() { //place it here })` it does work.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    //We load the masonry grids with an event
    var $grid = $(".searchResults").find('.resultGrid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.gridItem',
        gutter: '.gutterComponent'
    }).on("layoutComplete", function(event, laidOutItems) {
        console.log("It has loaded!");
        $(".searchResults").addClass("show");
    });

    //When we type something, we load again the masonry grid
    $(document).on("keyup", ".searchContainer input", function() {
        $grid.masonry();
    });

});
```

I cannot understand why if the code should be triggered once the whole page is loaded.

Comment: Which version you using, please share your markup or if possible jsfiddle.

Comment: Masonry version 4.2.1. I will try to make you the jsfiddle now

Comment: I cannot reach to understand how the heck is possible the same exact code I have in my local space does not work and on the jsfiddle it does...

Comment: @Hanif I updated the question. The thing was that the jquery code was inside a js file, but if I place the same code inside the callback of the load which brings the grid, it works. Any idea why this could happen in IE11?

Comment: I think this is initialization issue, without get the scenario it is hard to suggest you anything workable. Or any link where I can observe the scenario?

Comment: @Hanif sorry, there cant be. It's a menu that's loaded into the html main page via .load(). The issue appeared to be the function not being initialized even being inside a $(window).load(). My only work around, was making it like a function and call it on the same menu html itself or in the callback.